# SpecRepos private with credentials for cocoapods - Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

If we use a private repository, we cannot define the username and password.

```
cocoapods{
  //...
    specRepos {
        url("https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/cocoa-dev")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use private repository in some way?